# CSC vs. CSR matrix vector multiplication

Tags: python, scipy, matrix-multiplication

I have a python program that solves iterative methods for linear problem where the input data matrix is sparse.
My question is that which of the two compressed `scipy.sparse` formats, `csc` or `csr`, performs a **faster** matrix vector multiplication `A@x` and why? In other words, if I want to multiply a matrix from the left side to a vector is it more efficient to have it compressed in `csc` or `csr` format?

Comment: So `A` is the sparse matrix, and `x` an dense 1d array?  Roughly what the `A.shape`.  It's easy to switch between the formats, so you should be able to do your own time tests.  I wouldn't trust reasoning about the formats, without empirical confirmation.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for your answer. Yes, `A` is a sparse matrix with more rows than columns and `x` is a dense vector. So is not there any logic or a system which helps to find out how to choose the compression format based on some known information on `A` matrix?

Comment: `csr` will have an `indptr` the size of the number of rows (plus 1), `csc` it is number of columns.  So the `csc` will use less memory.  But that might not help with the `A@x` calculation, where the 'inner-most' iteration will be across columns  `ij,j->i` (sum on `j` in `einsum` notation).  What's wrong with experimenting?